# Trigger Release in Release management online

Tags: azure-devops, ms-release-management

Trigger Release in Release management online the way we do in on-prem calling webapi's

Are there any WebApi's to trigger ?

Answer :
https://{YourVSOName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/releaseManagement/OrchestratorService/InitiateRelease?releaseTemplateName={ReleaseTemplateName}

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it so that other folks who are looking for the solution can reference it.

Answer (score 1):

https://{YourVSOName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/releaseManagement/OrchestratorService/InitiateRelease?releaseTemplateName={ReleaseTemplateName}